# Adding functionality to mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm trying to rewrite [`grid_control.js`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/blob/v1/src/grid_control.js) in [MapBox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js) to allow for several tooltips from `gridControl` to appear together at the same time in the same box.

The `gridControl` is activated thus:

```
var gridLayer = L.mapbox.gridLayer('example-map.sdfagg22gd');
var tileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('example-map.sdfagg22gd')
map.addLayer(tileLayer);
map.addLayer(gridLayer);
map.addControl(L.mapbox.gridControl(gridLayer));
```

Instead of rewriting the source code, however, I'd like to extend the `GridControl` class, and make the code more compatible with future `mapbox.js` versions.

```
var GridControl = L.Control.extend({

options: {
    pinnable: true,
    follow: false,
    sanitizer: require('sanitize-caja'),
    touchTeaser: true,
    location: true
},
```

How should I do that, and is it advisable?

Also, any ideas on how to allow for several tooltips at the same time?  Will I need a counter for active tooltips and redo all actions based on that? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

From what I understand, the possibility for concurrent tooltips is possible, as two separate boxes with tooltip content will appear with `{follow : false}` option.  But how to get this into a mouse-centric moving tooltip (which is activated by `{follow: true}`)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
// get gridControl object and pass it for modification
var gridControl = L.mapbox.gridControl(gridLayer, {follow:true});

// modify the prototype
gridControl.__proto__._onPopupClose = function() {
   this._currentContent = null;
   this._lastContent = null;
   this._pinned = false;
};
```